# Кавычки в жаргонных словах

Tags: стилистика, пунктуация

Если в тексте, вполне приличном, вставлено жаргонное слово, нужно ли его брать в кавычки? Вот, скажем, из гороскопа: "Семейных Дев будет слегка *колбасить*, но делать резких движений в сторону расставания не стоит". Гороскоп не шуточный.

Comment: Не могу считать гороскоп серьезным текстом ни в каком случае )))

Comment: Не в том смысле "серьёзный".  
Он написан серьёзным языком - и не в качестве шутки.  
А в плане отношения к подобным изыскам - это да. Я их тоже к "серьёзнному" чтиву не отноше.

Comment: Дело в том, что есть заведомо шуточные гороскопы, а есть написанные без шутливого оттенка. Вот и вся разница. А кто как к ним относится — это личное дело каждого и к данному вопросу отношения не имеет.

Comment: @behemothus и @Fuchoin Kazuki - вот вы действительно серьезны! Мне казалось, я поставила достаточно "улыбок )) ", чтобы не реагировать на мое высказывание серьезно.  

Впрочем, можно сказать и по сути: гороскоп - не научное сочинение, оно рассчитано на легковерного читателя, к которому надо подстроиться. так что требовать от него литературности не стоит.

Comment: А вот тут я не совсем согласен. Авторы и потребители подобных творений относятся (могут относиться) к ним весьма серьёзно. Наше общее мнение о несерьёзности сего занятия - не аргумент. 

ЗЫ Неужели вам никогда не приходилось читать всякой разной чуши, написанной вполне серьёзным языком?

Comment: Я не говорю, что для них занятие несерьезно. Просто каждый "гороскоповаятель" работает в своем секторе рынка. Эти, видимо, хотели показаться "своими парнями". Другие давят на научность.

Comment: Возможно. Но это уже настолько далеко от темы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, возьмите слово в кавычки. Оно выбивается, на мой взгляд, из любого стиля, и кавычками Вы покажете, что видите это, но сегодня допускаете слово в текст и просите за это прощения.

Answer (score 2):

Приличный текст (тем более серьёзный) не должен содержать жаргонных слов. Тогда и вопросов возникать не будет.

Comment: А если человек вычитывает готовый текст? Вы это пойдите и автору текста скажите.  
Вам конкретный вопрос задали — или отвечайте корректно, или, если нечего ответить, просто промолчите.  
Администрация.

Comment: Мне вообще-то тоже кажется это слово не совсем здесь уместным.

Answer (score 1):

Сильно зависит от контекста. Шуточность или серьёзность текста здесь не столько важна. Главно то, используется ли слово (в подобных текстах) в основном значении или нет, - и вообще насколько уместны пободные слова.
Здесь я бы кавычки поставил. Или выделил курсивом, как в примере. Но если при этом окажется, что текст пестрит такими кавычками, то их лучше убрать везде. Вроеде как получится, что эти слова здесь в обычном (для данного текста) употреблении.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, я не вижу здесь особого предмета для спора, так как существует правило, что в кавычки берутся слова, употребленные в данном тексте в переносном значении. Это как раз тот случай, поэтому кавычки нужны, хотя слово "колбасить" относится к жаргонной, точнее к сленговой лексике. В этом случае к такому слову можно мысленно подставить "так сказать"

Answer (score 0):

Если  "колбасить"  в  переносном  значении,  то  в  прямом  -  как ?  Слово  "кошмарить" образовано  от  слова  "кошмар"  и  употреблено  в  прямом  значении.  Это  не  сленг,  а  разговорное. "Колбасить" - сленг.  В  каком  оно  значении  в  нашем  случае - прямом  или  в  переносном ?

Не  знаю,  что  точно  означает  слово  "колбасить",  но  полагаю,  что  оно  употреблено  не  в  переносном  значении.  Поэтому  кавычки  здесь  не  нужны,  лучше  использовать  курсив,  что  и  было  сделано  в  тексте  примера.

Comment: Отвечаю  Клименту.

Answer (score 0):

по-моему это слово равнозначно по статусу с словом "кошмарить", употреблённое первым лицом государства в одном из монологов. а разве первое лицо может себе позволить публично выражаться сленгами. кто позволит в-о-з-в-р-а-з-и-т-ь???

Answer (score -2):

Когда первое лицо государства употребило выражение " мочить в сортире", то все прекрасно поняли для кого именно оно было произнесено.... Также и в данном случае: гороскопы пишутся для широкого круга людей с разным уровнем восприятия информации.Поэтому. выражаться словами близкими  для понимания как можно большему количеству людей. есть необходимость составителей сих перлов. Не сомневаюсь и в том, что авторы даже преднамеренно ввернули этакое словечко.( Главное  не в том, чтобы грамотно, а в том, чтобы колбасило от прочитанного!) Вот такие, понимаешь. пошли времена....

Comment: А какое это отношение имеет к кавычкам?

Comment: Автор ясно высказался против кавычек и объяснил о чём идёт речь.